# Android Second Layout Event Listener Error

Tags: android, layout

I can make listener button or other widgets in MainLayout but when I pass second layout the button's listener doesn't work. how can I fix it

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bilsay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button item1,item2,btn3,btnonay,btnsedef;
    TextView item3,itemtxt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        item1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btntıkla);
        item2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        item3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        btnsedef=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);


        btn3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnsedef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                item3.setText("Sedef Bilsayın sevgilisidir");

            }
        });

        item1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                item3.setText("Hoşgeldiniz");
            }
        });

        item2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                item3.setText("Merhaba Mavi");

            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setContentView(R.layout.che);


            }
        });


    }
```

Second layout
che.java : 
the second layout is seen but actionlisteners do not work ; these code do not work.

```
package com.example.bilsay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class che extends Activity{

    CheckBox chkc1,chkc2,chkc3,chkc4,chkc5;
    ImageView image;
    Button btnonay,btntıkla;

    TextView itemtxt;
    int c=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bilsayiyicocuktur) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(bilsayiyicocuktur);
        setContentView(R.layout.che);

        Thread timer=new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                    //Class myclass=Class.forName("com.example.bilsay.che");


                }
                catch(InterruptedException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{
                    Intent openChe =new Intent("com.example.bilsay.che");                   
                    startActivity(openChe);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        chkc1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        chkc2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        chkc3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        chkc4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        chkc5=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        btnonay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnonay);
        image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        itemtxt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.chesonuc);
        btntıkla=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnblsay);
        btntıkla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                c++;
                itemtxt.setText("Tıkladın "+c);


            }
        });
        btnonay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                itemtxt.setText("el mature");
                if(chkc1.isChecked()){
                    itemtxt.setText("Kisi");}
                else if(chkc2.isChecked())
                    itemtxt.setText("Rahmetli Arjantinli Devrimci");
                else if(chkc3.isChecked())
                    itemtxt.setText("Ben");
                else if(chkc4.isChecked())
                    itemtxt.setText("Nimet anlamnıa gelir");
                else if(chkc5.isChecked())
                    itemtxt.setText("el mature");



            }
        });
    }

}
```

che.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hangisinin Anlamını Öğrenmek İstiyorsun ???"
        android:textSize="23dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="El Peblo" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Che" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bilsay" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Namet" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Olgun" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnonay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Onay!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chesonuc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sonuç:"
        android:textSize="@dimen/bigdimension" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnblsay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tıkla" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your `che.xml` file

Comment: can you please tell the exact problem orelse post the logcat result as well as the xml in which activity you are facing problem

Comment: i edited by adding che.xml

Comment: my mainactivity has no problem . its buttons work but orher activity is only seen but any button of its does not work